# I purchased iTunes music and no longer want the subscription. How do I cancel my subscripition?

Tags: music

I no longer want my subscription of iTunes music - how do I cancel my subscription?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from your Account page in iTunes. Apple has a support page on this, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202039

Comment: Hi Patrix! We tend to prefer answers that are more than link only. Could you add relevant information from the link to the body of your answer? :P

Comment: @JMY1000 well, copying the whole support article seems to be rather extreme :-)

Comment: How about the "Change or cancel subscriptions billed through Apple" section?